# nginx close a location with auth_basic, if a certain argument was passed

Tags: nginx

There is the URL `/index.php`. Access to it should be restricted, if it has argument ‘foo’ set to, say, ‘bar’, i.e. `/index.php` should open freely by anyone, and opening `/index.php?foo=bar` should proceed only after basic authorisation. I know about the `if` directive,

```
location = index.php {
    if ($arg_foo ~ bar) {
        auth_basic "";
        auth_basic_user_file myauth;  
    }
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.socket;
}
```

…but a separate `location` with `if` doesn’t allow `auth_basic` to be put inside of an `if` clause. So I thought there should be some kind of `rewrite` to another location, probably passing a header containing the original location we wanted to get to, check the header and after passing the authentication, rewrite to that location, but this all looks like too much of a hack and probably can be done easier, but I don’t know how.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [`map`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map), since [`auth_basic`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_basic_module.html#auth_basic) has a special `off` value disabling authentication:

```
http {
    [...]
    map $arg_foo $auth_realm {
        default off;
        ~bar    "";
    }

    server {
        [...]
        location = /index.php {
            auth_basic $auth_realm;
            auth_basic_user_file myauth;

            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.socket;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I suspect the configuration snippet you provided is not working, since the URI prefix of the `location` directive does not start with the mandatory `/` character.