# Does not work nginx htaccess for special page in redmine

Tags: nginx, .htaccess, password, redmine

i have system of management of projects redmine. Also, i have nginx, like reverse proxy for redmine. So, i need to block some page in redmine, for users. In `redmine.conf`, i did:

```
location /projects/wwe/dmsf
{
        auth_basic "Test4";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/legalinfopass;
        alias /usr/share/redmine/public;
        try_files $uri @fcgi;
}
```

I generated `htaccess` file via `htpasswd`. It works. But i need to block deeper page. 
I want something like

```
location /projects/wwe/dmsf?folder_id=351
{
        auth_basic "Test4";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/legalinfopass;
        alias /usr/share/redmine/public;
        try_files $uri @fcgi;
}
```

But, when i am going to page `/projects/wwe/dmsf?folder_id=351`, i don't have proposition of password and login. Where i made error ?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Do you want to block access or put a password on? Please include the full nginx.conf to show that it's including redmine.conf

Comment: The `?folder_id=351` is a query string and is not part of the normalised URI used to evaluate `location` and `rewrite` directives.

Comment: However, the first `location` block also matches the URL with query string. Do you want to only block a page with a specific query string?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen yes, i want to block query string.

Comment: That is unclear. Do you want to block a page with a specific query string, block any URL with a query string or what?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen ONLY THIS QUERY `/projects/wwe/dmsf?folder_id=351`

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/780192/nginx-close-a-location-with-auth-basic-if-a-certain-argument-was-passed has an answer how to implement auth based on a query string.